# Weed and water "skirt" around a slab

Tags: slab

I'm working on plans to put a "skirt" around the slab of the house both for weed control/ termite visual inspection and to stop any water pooling against the slab.

I've settled on crushed concrete aggregate.

My thoughts, which I'd love your feedback on, is to use clay / soil from around the site, tamp it at a slight angle away from the slab, then put something (crusher dust, screenings?) down, geofabric, then aggregate.

Does that sound about right? Am i missing something? Over thinking it? Someone suggested stabilised sand rather than crusher dust / screenings - overkill?

Thoughts most welcome.

Cheers

Comment: It may take a few years, but you'll have weeds. Dust, organic material and weed seeds will collect above the geotextile - and weeds will happen.

Comment: I'm curious how this will help with "termite visual inspection". Not doubting you, just not understanding.

Comment: Ercnewal - yeah understand this. inevitable for sure but I feel weeds will be easily removed as they dont have a strong rootbase due to the geofabric.

Comment: Freeman - the aggregate will have a 100 - 150mm gap to the top of the slab so we'll see any termite tunnels running up to to the timber frames.

Comment: I've seen weeds on top grow roots right through fabric, but I can't swear it was "proper geofabric" as opposed to "crappy misnamed weed barrier."

Comment: yeah agree. Did you put anything like roadbase or screenings down under the geo?